# Google AutoComplete API address components

Tags: ios, swift, google-api

I am using the google API in my swift app to get addresses. I am trying to retrieve the city of the address which I assume will be in the address components.

When I use the code below it returns code which I am not familiar with:

```html
Address components: Optional([<GMSAddressComponent: 0x17022b540>, <GMSAddressComponent: 0x170234b20>, <GMSAddressComponent: 0x17022b9a0>, <GMSAddressComponent: 0x17022cf80>, <GMSAddressComponent: 0x17022bb00>, <GMSAddressComponent: 0x170234f60>, <GMSAddressComponent: 0x1702346c0>, <GMSAddressComponent: 0x17022d580>])
```

How would I go about making this readable and retrieving the city name from it?

Any help much appreciated

```html
extension selectAddress: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

    // Handle the user's selection.
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

        print("Address components: \(place.addressComponents)")

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: You should always check for component type first to make sure you are getting the correct address component...
[Check this answer for a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44113639/1918259)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it

let city = place.addressComponents?[2].name

Comment: This is higly discouraged from google: "The format of the response is not guaranteed to remain the same between requests. [...] In particular, the number of addressComponents varies based on the address requested and can change over time for the same address. A component can change position in the array. The type of the component can change. A particular component may be missing in a later response. https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/place-details