# How to extract street, city, etc. from GMSPlace Address Components

Tags: ios, swift3, google-places-api

I'm using Google Places API for iOS and can successfully retrieve nearby places and present the address as a string.  What I'm trying to do is extract address components such as city to store in a database.

The documentation indicates a GMSPlace has an addressComponents property (an array), but I can't seem to figure how to use this property.

The code below provides sets the entire address to the text of a label, but I can't get beyond that:

Edit ---- added code that shows how I'm trying to access Address Components

```
venueLabel.isHidden = false
            venueLabel.text = selectedPlace?.name
            addressLabel.isHidden = false
            addressLabel.text = selectedPlace?.formattedAddress
            let addressComponents = selectedPlace?.addressComponents
            for component in addressComponents! {
                let city = component["city"] //Error Type GMSPaceAddressComponent has no subscript members
                print(city)
            }
```

Comment: share full code please.

Comment: All the details of `addressComponents` are mentioned in the API docs.  See  this https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place.html#ae0c1f39cee593fcf0909bcdf16ae2761

Comment: @Shabirjan just edited with additional code

Comment: you need to check component.type == "city" then retrive the component.name for city information

Comment: let addressComponent = place?.addressComponents?.first(where: {$0.types.contains("city")})

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A safe Swift 4.2 solution:

```
let name = place.addressComponents?.first(where: { $0.type == "city" })?.name
```

---

selectedPlace.addressComponents is a array of **GMSAddressComponent** which have 2 properties type and name.
In you case it will be like

```
    for component in addressComponents! {
    if component.type == "city" {
    print(component.name)
    }
   }
```

GMSAddressComponent is a class not a dictionary or array that's you are getting this error.

Additional component types can be referred from the [link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/supported_types#table2).

Comment: Thanks.  Now it makes perfect sense.  Cheers!

Comment: @FadiAbuzant That is correct. My change to this answer is pending, but until then, please use the `types` array property instead of `type` on GMSAddressComponent. Check to see if that array contains the kGMSPlaceTypeLocality type. The different GMSPlaceTypes are defined in GMSPlaceTypes.h in v3.1.0 of the Google Places SDK for iOS. Happy coding!

Comment: @FateNuller please update this answer. I will make sure you answer will be visible here.

Comment: @SurjeetRajput My edit was rejected by two reviewers for the same reason: "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner." This doesn't sound accurate to me considering my edits only updated the existing content in order to be relevant with the latest version of the Google Places API. Since this post does not specify a version, I'd say it's reasonable to assume the latest.

Comment: type property is deprecated now in favor of types

Comment: New link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/supported_types#table2

Answer (score 5):

For the latest Google Places API (July 2019) this is what could help you.
Actually, Google now putting a couple of types for each element. So the "type" is now deprecated and "types" is new filed.

You can do something like this:

```
 for addressComponent in (self.mySelectedPlace?.addressComponents)! {
            for type in (addressComponent.types){

                switch(type){
                    case "country":
                        var country = addressComponent.name

                    case "postal_code":
                         var postCode = addressComponent.name

                default:
                    break
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4

```
    var keys = [String]()
    place.addressComponents?.forEach{keys.append($0.type)}
    var values = [String]()
    place.addressComponents?.forEach({ (component) in
        keys.forEach{ component.type == $0 ? values.append(component.name): nil}
    })
    print(values)
```

Answer (score 4):

**It's working in Swift 5 and iOS 13.3**

**1. Create a function for showing GMSAutocompleteViewController**

```
    func googlePlacesSearchVC() {
    
        let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        acController.delegate = self
        // Specify the place data types to return.
        let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) |
      UInt(GMSPlaceField.formattedAddress.rawValue)  |
               UInt(GMSPlaceField.addressComponents.rawValue))!
    
        acController.placeFields = fields
        // Specify a filter.
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.country = "IN"
        acController.autocompleteFilter = filter

        acController.secondaryTextColor = .darkGray
        acController.primaryTextColor = .lightGray
        acController.primaryTextHighlightColor = .black
        acController.tableCellBackgroundColor = .whiteThree
        acController.tableCellSeparatorColor = .lightGray
        // Display the autocomplete view controller.
        present(acController, animated: true) {

            let views = acController.view.subviews
            let subviewsOfSubview = views.first!.subviews
            let subOfNavTransitionView = subviewsOfSubview[1].subviews
            let subOfContentView = subOfNavTransitionView[1].subviews
            let searchBar = subOfContentView[0] as! UISearchBar
            searchBar.searchTextField.placeholder = "places_picker_hint_add_address".localized
            searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
            searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont.screenTitle16Pt
            searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            searchBar.searchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = .darkGray
            searchBar.delegate?.searchBar?(searchBar, textDidChange: "")
        }
   }
```

**2. Call that function where ever you need, for ex:-**

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      googlePlacesSearchVC()
   }
```

**3. Call GMSAutoCompleteViewControllerDelegates Methods.
Here will get all details like Street, City, etc. from GMSPlace Address Components**

```
extension ViewController {

      // Handle the user's selection.
      func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        
            // Show HouseAndFlat
            if place.name?.description != nil {
                
                yourTxtField.text = place.name?.description ?? ""
            }

            // Show latitude
            if place.coordinate.latitude.description.count != 0 {
                var latitude = place.coordinate.latitude
            }
            // Show longitude
            if place.coordinate.longitude.description.count != 0 {
                selectedLongitude = place.coordinate.longitude
            }

            // Show AddressComponents
            if place.addressComponents != nil {
                
                for addressComponent in (place.addressComponents)! {
                   for type in (addressComponent.types){

                       switch(type){
                           case "sublocality_level_2":
                               yourTxtField.text = addressComponent.name
                           case "sublocality_level_1":
                                yourTxtField.text = addressComponent.name
                            case "administrative_area_level_2":
                                yourTxtField.text = addressComponent.name

                            case "administrative_area_level_1":
                                 yourTxtField.text = addressComponent.name
                            case "country":
                                yourTxtField.text = addressComponent.name

                            case "postal_code":
                                 yourTxtField.text = addressComponent.name
                       default:
                           break
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      }

      func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
            // TODO: handle the error.
            print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
      }

      // User canceled the operation.
      func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
}
```

[I have found an answer from this link](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/50792616.shtml)

Comment: How can i find Street Address and Apartment/Suite from GMSPlace??

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology **print("addressComponents :-", place.addressComponents as Any)** you will get list of array. What u need just check it.

Comment: OutStanding Working for me.........

Answer (score 2):

I am using this extension:

```
extension Array where Element == GMSAddressComponent {
    func valueFor(placeType: String, shortName: Bool = false) -> String? {
        // bug in the google or apple framework. This cast must stay.
        // Withou it crashing.
        guard let array = self as? NSArray else { return nil }
        let result = array
            .compactMap { $0 as? GMSAddressComponent }
            .first(where: {
                $0.types
                    .first(where: { $0 == placeType }) == placeType
            })
        return shortName ? result?.shortName : result?.name
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let place: GMSPlace
// ...
place.addressComponents?.valueFor(placeType: kGMSPlaceTypeRoute, shortName: true)
```

Comment: Thread 1: Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Comment: @EgzonArifi I did made changes to the extension. Please take a look now.

Comment: Good one @Ramis

Answer (score 2):

I will extend @Ramis answer, in any case you want to check for multiple types if one of them exist, e.x

```
addressComponents?.valueFor(placeTypes: kGMSPlaceTypePostalTown, kGMSPlaceTypeLocality)
```

implementation

```
extension Array where Element == GMSAddressComponent {
    func valueFor(placeTypes: String..., shortName: Bool = false) -> String? {
        let array = self as NSArray
        let result = array
            .compactMap { $0 as? GMSAddressComponent }
            .first(where: {
                placeTypes.contains($0.types.first(where: { placeTypes.contains($0) }) ?? "")
            })
        return shortName ? result?.shortName : result?.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Too funny!  I am going through this course again to get back up to speed on GeoLocation.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I could not find this anywhere for Objective-C, for those who follow behind me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [place.addressComponents count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"name %@ = type %@", place.addressComponents[i].name, place.addressComponents[i].type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( GMSAddressComponent * component in place.addressComponents) {
    if ( [component.type  isEqual: @"locality"] )
    {
        NSLog(@"Current city %@ ", component.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Please explain why your code solves the problem. Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

```
var keys = [String]()
    place.addressComponents?.forEach{keys.append($0.type)}
    var values = [String]()
    place.addressComponents?.forEach({ (component) in
        keys.forEach{ component.type == $0 ? values.append(component.name): nil}

         print("All component type \(component.type)")

       if component.type == "locality"{
            print("This is city name \(component.name)")
        }
    })
    print(values)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this, I hope I help you

```
  let arrays : NSArray = place.addressComponents! as NSArray
        for i in 0..<arrays.count {

            let dics : GMSAddressComponent = arrays[i] as! GMSAddressComponent
            let str : NSString = dics.type as NSString

            if (str == "country") {
                print("Country: \(dics.name)")
                self.pais = dics.name
            }

            else if (str == "administrative_area_level_2") {
                print("City: \(dics.name)")
                self.ciudad = dics.name
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

print("City: (String(describing: place.addressComponents?.first(where: {$0.type == "locality"})?.name))")
print("Postal Code: (String(describing: place.addressComponents?.first(where: {$0.type == "postal_code"})?.name))")
print("State: (String(describing: place.addressComponents?.first(where: {$0.type == "administrative_area_level_1"})?.name))"

Use this description for work like this.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/place-data-fields